# How to set context from request header using graphql-java

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

I want to be able to set a context variable from the http request header I receive from the request. This will be a jwt token so I can identify my user on every query.

```
package br.com.b2breservas.api;

import com.google.common.base.Charsets;
import com.google.common.io.Resources;
import graphql.GraphQL;
import graphql.schema.GraphQLSchema;
import graphql.schema.idl.RuntimeWiring;
import graphql.schema.idl.SchemaGenerator;
import graphql.schema.idl.SchemaParser;
import graphql.schema.idl.TypeDefinitionRegistry;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import static graphql.schema.idl.TypeRuntimeWiring.newTypeWiring;

@Component
public class GraphQLProvider   {


    @Autowired
    GraphQLDataFetchers graphQLDataFetchers;

    private GraphQL graphQL;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws IOException {
        URL url = Resources.getResource("schema.graphqls");
        String sdl = Resources.toString(url, Charsets.UTF_8);
        GraphQLSchema graphQLSchema = buildSchema(sdl);
        this.graphQL = GraphQL.newGraphQL(graphQLSchema).build();
    }

    private GraphQLSchema buildSchema(String sdl) {
        TypeDefinitionRegistry typeRegistry = new SchemaParser().parse(sdl);
        RuntimeWiring runtimeWiring = buildWiring();
        SchemaGenerator schemaGenerator = new SchemaGenerator();
        return schemaGenerator.makeExecutableSchema(typeRegistry, runtimeWiring);
    }

    private RuntimeWiring buildWiring() {
        return RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring()
                .type(newTypeWiring("Query")
                        .dataFetcher("books", graphQLDataFetchers.getBooks()))
                .type(newTypeWiring("Query")
                        .dataFetcher("bookById", graphQLDataFetchers.getBookByIdDataFetcher()))
                .type(newTypeWiring("Book")
                        .dataFetcher("author", graphQLDataFetchers.getAuthorDataFetcher()))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public GraphQL graphQL() {
        return graphQL;
    }

}
```

Comment: hello, where do you import class (or interface?) `GraphQLDataFetchers` from? I couldn't find any relevant class on the internet as many libraries seem to have it...

Comment: @maxxyme is the class where you write your code. just create anywhere and import it. just use the spring Component decorator on it and you are ready to go. something like 
https://gist.github.com/cescoferraro/385e2bd40ddbd2c6afda9a7e79d858ad

Comment: That's weird because with GraphQL Java Tools I don't have to write such a class nor I don't need to write such provider...

Answer (score 2):

You can create a customized object which internally contain the JWT or simply the `HttpServletRequest` :

```
public class GraphQLContext {
    private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;
}
```

When executing a `GraphQL` query , you create this context object and set it to the `ExecutionInput`. Most web framework should provide some ways to access the current `HttpServletRequest` easily :

```
GraphQLContext context = new GraphQLContext(httpServletRequest);
ExecutionInput executionInput = ExecutionInput.newExecutionInput()
                .query(query)
                .context(context)
                .build();

ExecutionResult result = graphQL.execute(executionInput);
```

Then in the data fetcher , the context can be get by :

```
@Override
public Object get(DataFetchingEnvironment env) throws Exception {

    GraphQLContext context = env.getContext();
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = context.getHttpServletRequest();

}
```

Comment: I dont understand. The client is an Apollo client, it will send Auth header on que request. I want to read this token from spring-boot somehow and set it as a context variable so I can use it on the DataFetchers. Where should I put this code

Comment: So how to do receive the GraphQL http request now ? If you are using MVC controller ,you can simply put `HttpServletRequest` parameter in your controller method ..

Comment: Spring boot. @ken chan

Comment: it is the same , most probably springboot use mvc behind scene . but if you use webflux , just change the request parameter type to `ServerHttpRequest` instead

Comment: I think I am using a dependencie that handles the http post request behind the scenes. I might have to overwrite it so I can inject the context to it. Does it make sense? https://github.com/b2breservas/java/blob/9e974487e8222faf05767a98133cad2263197870/build.gradle#L42

Comment: this is what I need to do
https://spectrum.chat/graphql-java/general/getting-the-token-from-request-header~7100992c-6910-43cd-b2c1-0b0381136a7a

Comment: https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-spring#beans GraphQLInvocation

Comment: Glad to hear .  You should mention `graphql-java-spring` next time such that we know you use it for serving the web service .

Answer (score 2):

You can inject (or Autowire) your custom `GraphQLInvocation` instance which can act as an interceptor for all requests handled by `GraphQL`

```
import graphql.ExecutionInput
import graphql.ExecutionResult
import graphql.GraphQL
import graphql.spring.web.servlet.GraphQLInvocation
import graphql.spring.web.servlet.GraphQLInvocationData
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture

@Component
@Primary // <= Mark it as Primary to override the default one
class ErsanGraphQLInvocation(private val graphQL: GraphQL) : GraphQLInvocation {
    override fun invoke(invocationData: GraphQLInvocationData,
        webRequest: WebRequest): CompletableFuture<ExecutionResult> {

        val context = "Context" //Basically any class you want <=====

        val executionInput = ExecutionInput.newExecutionInput()
            .query(invocationData.query)
            .operationName(invocationData.operationName)
            .variables(invocationData.variables)
            .context(context)
            .build()
        return graphQL.executeAsync(executionInput)
    }
}
```

and then in your `DataFetcher`, you can read the context from the `DataFetchingEnvironment` instance, eg.

```
fun appVersionFetcher(): DataFetcher<Boolean> {
    return DataFetcher { dataFetchingEnvironment ->
        val context = dataFetchingEnvironment.getContext<String>()
        println("Context $context")
        false
    }
}
```